# How to host a game/server in LAN so that client can search and connect with it in Android?

Tags: android, client-server, multiplayer, lan

I am trying to develop LAN Multiplayer game in Android. I would want the host to create a server/ start a game in the network. Then the client who is in the same network will search for the server to connect with it. This is similar to the Mini Militia Game (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsomniacs.da2&hl=en). I want to implement this server-client model. How to do?

Comment: So your server is ready? And your client app is ready?

Comment: The client can determine its own ip address. Lets say it's 192.168.0.12. Then the client should just try the possible ips like 192.168.0.3 and up. (Not its own). Set a timeout of one second.

Comment: Yes I have my server and client ready. But this method will be time consuming and inefficient right? @greenapps

Comment: No. What i tried to tell you is that it is pretty quick and simple.

Comment: Yes it looks simple but its not quite working out for me as it should try all the possibilities and takes time. Now, I found this solution which is based on UDP Broadcast (Found here: [link])(https://jackiexie.com/2015/07/15/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast-java/). This is good. Anyway Thank You for your prompt suggestions @greenapps. I now have two solutions in hand.

Comment: Yes those gamers are too impatient to wailt six seconds for a connection ;-). And indeed this UTP broadcast is the more official way to go.